# Self referential Structure

Tags: c++

I am writing 2 codes for self referential structures :

1st:

```
struct node
{

    int a;
    struct node *link;

};

int main()
{

    struct node n;

    n.a = 5;

    cout<< n.a << "\t" ;

    cout << n.link ;

    return 0;

}
```

Output : ̀ 5   0x40185b`

2nd:

```
struct node{

    int a;
    struct node *link;

};

int main(){

    struct node n;

    n.a = 5;

    cout << n.a << "\t";

    cout << *n.link ;

    return 0;

}
```

Output: error:link was not declared in this scope.

Please tell me what is really happening in the code??

Why does a garbage value is thrown??

How can I initialize a self referential structure pointer??

Comment: `error:link was not declared in this scope.` Is this a runtime error? Does not look like.

Comment: Read a good C++ programming book then look into some [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp); your question needs some [MCVE] and is off-topic here

Comment: Funny, I get a completely different error https://ideone.com/Y6QQzl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that's what you want to do:

```
int main(){

    struct node n;
    n.a = 5;
    n.link = NULL; // initialize the link
    cout << n.a << "\t";
    cout << n.link;

    return 0;

}
```

`*(n.link)` will only be valid if `n.link` points to a valid `node` object.
And `cout << *(n.link);` will only be valid if you declare an `operator<<` for `node` (`cout << n.link;` is valid as it outputs the adress, not the value).

For instance, this would work much better:

```
#include <iostream>

struct node{
    int a;
    node *link; // Note: no need to prefix with struct
};

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& str, const struct node& n )
{   
    str << n.a << "\t -> ";
    if ( n.link )
        str << *n.link;
    else
        str << "NULL";

    return str;
}

int main(){

    node n1; // Note: no need to prefix with struct
    node n2; // Note: no need to prefix with struct

    n1.a = 5;
    n1.link = &n2;

    n2.a = 6;
    n2.link = NULL;

    cout << n1;

    return 0;

}
```

It outputs `5    -> 6    -> NULL`

Comment: As this is C++, you should use `node a1;`, not `struct node a1`.  You could also remove the `using namespace std` if you wrote `std::cout` at the bottom.

Comment: @MartinBonner: True, fixed that